# Page does not resize to iPhone screen

Tags: ios, iphone, html, css, responsive-design

I have designed a magazine for the iPad and now I would like to make it available for the iPhone as well. The problem is that the html pages of the magazine do not fully resize to the iPhone's width and about 30% of the page remains hidden to the right and needs scrolling/dragging.

I would like the page to 100% fit horizontally and be centred vertically.

I have already tried to change `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1536"/>` for `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>` and while there is no change on the iPad, on the iPhone the page simply resized to the device's height and therefore it needs even more scrolling to the right.

The magazine only has portrait mode.

Comment: Have you tried something like `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">` (or `yes`)? This always works for my projects…

Comment: @Xufox Yes, I've tried that too, but it did not work.